# Одна система, много сайтов

Tags: php, codeigniter

У меня есть VPS, на ней 10 сайтов, на одной и той же системе ImageCMS, и каждый сайт использует свои файлы этой системы. Есть ли возможность, либо системы или скрипты, методы для того чтобы все сайты использовали основные файлы этой системы из одной директории. а в папках доменов были только файлы config.php и папка templates.

Возможно ли такое? Кстати, система на CodeIgniter.

Comment: возможно.., у меня сайты используют одну папку с фреймворком )
надо только правильно настроить )

Comment: А примерно в какую сторону копать? Что настроить? Где? и как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что в `index.php` надо вместо:

```
$system_path = 'system';
```

написать

```
$system_path = '../system';
```

И вынести эту `system` вверх.

Если перестанет находить файлы, то смотрите в сторону [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Comment: А что касается ImageCMS, то, насколько я понял - это платная система, потому стоило бы обратиться в поддержку.

Comment: Не, там есть платная для интернет-магазинов, а есть бесплатная корпоративная версия. Поддержка на данный момент - это их слабая сторона) всё остальное меня устраивает. Но сейчас пришёл к тому что хочу делать с нуля на CodeIgniter, ибо скорость работы последнего сайта вдохновила клиента)

Comment: Ага, действительно. Посмотрел - они, вроде, ничего не изменили, а значит ответ должен быть верным и для CMS.

Answer (score -1):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ƹ%F1%F2%EA%E0%FF_%F1%F1%FB%EB%EA%E0

В линуксах насколько знаю тоже есть, это если ради экономии места делается.

Comment: в вашем случае, ищем все одинаковые файлы и делаем hardling

Comment: Зачем жесткую, если можно символическую ссылку сделать?

Comment: как апач(или что там) воспримет символическую ссылку?
жесткую - не отличит от файла.

Comment: Слышал что можно просто вынести файлы фреймворка за видимую область, а в самих доменах разместить только основные файлы, ии указать им путь до ядра, которое находится в папке выше уровнем. Только вот не знаю как это провернуть с CI.